# Editting Certain note in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius

I have an issue in Sibelius, where I want to edit a certain note in the whole score (the same note in many octaves), for example the D note, which is highlighted in red to a B note (4 semitones down).

[image]

I am using Sibelius 7.5.

Comment: Which version of Sibelius are you using?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1sfbl5&s=8#.VcN5PbVUK70

I am using Sibelius 7.5.

Comment: You link to a picture that looks like an original score, rather than a Sibelius file. Have you already scanned this into Sibelius using Photoscore?

Answer (score 3):

When using Sibelius7 (or 7.5) you can use the **Filters** function to select a group of similar objects (notes, rests, text etc.). This then allows you to perform the same action on all of these selected objects. The **Filters** functions are found on the **Home** tab (towards the right-hand side of the image below):

[image]

I'll demonstrate how to use this feature with a short excerpt from the music you link to. Here it is with the Ds unchanged:

[image]

If you click on the **Advanced** button next to the **Filters** button, you will open a pane giving you a large number of options for which characteristics you want filtered objects to have:

[image]

To select all the Ds in your score:

- select **Notes and Chords** from the left-hand list.

[image]

- select **Single** next to **Pitch**.

[image]

- select **D** under **Sounding** as the pitch you want to select (leave the option next to it set to **Any**, to select this pitch in any octave).

[image]

If you now click on the **Select** button, in the bottom right-hand corner of the pane, all the Ds in your score will be selected (assuming you left the option **Find in: Whole score** selected in the top left-hand corner of the pane):

[image]

Now you can simply press the down-arrow key twice to move all of these Ds down to Bs:

[image]

I did this in Sibelius7, but I doubt it is significantly different in Sibelius7.5.